# PostgreSQL check parent of parent in query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, recursive-query

Okay, I'll try to be as precise as possible. I have a database with comments who have a parent_comment_id. I want to select a number of comments from this table and a matching number of answers to these comments. Here comes my problem: If I arbitrarily select comments, I might grab some who don't have any answers. However, if I select comment answers first, I might grab answers who are an answer to another comment already. So, what I want to do is grab answers who are immediate answers to a comment (parent_comment_id = NULL) and then get those comments base on the parent_comment_id. How would I go about this in a query?

Assume this layout of a database

```
comment_id    parent_comment_id
1             NULL
2             NULL
3             1
4             3
5             1
6             3
7             1
8             4
9             NULL
10            NULL
...
```

Now, I would select, let's say 2 answers and the corresponding comments. If I just select the first 2 answers, I would get comment 3 and 4, but if I backtrace those, I would only get comment 1, because comment 4 is an answer to an answer. Instead, I would want to find only comments whose parent comment has no parent comment, which would be comment 3 and 5 in this example.

I haven't really tried anything beyound realizing it doesn't work without somehow recursively getting parents which I have no clue how to do in SQL queries.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your requirement. Also, have you attempted anything at this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a pretty easy solution. Might be horrible practice, but works for my use-case ^^

For the given example it would be something like this:

```
select distinct on (parent_comment_id) c.id, c.parent_comment_id, c.text
from comments c
where parent_comment_id is not null
and (select parent_comment_id from comments p where id = c.parent_comment_id) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would want to find only comments whose parent comment has no parent comment.

I think that you just want a self-join and some filtering:

```
select c.*
from comments c
inner join comments pc on pc.comment_id = c.parent_comment_id
where pc.parent_comment_id is null
```

You could also use `exists`:

```
select c.*
from comments c
where exists (
    select 1 
    from comments pc 
    where pc.comment_id = c.parent_comment_id and pc.parent_comment_id is null
)
```